# Shipment Goods Tracking software / Storing and retrieving information

Tags: gratis, open-source, project-management, shipment

I have a question regarding storing and retrieving shipping data information.

I searched the web and failed perhaps because I was using the wrong search terms but this is the situation:

We need a software that can store information on our shipments that we organize

```
Supplier | Freight Forward | Goods | Container Size | ETD | ETA | New Rate Price | old Price| Delivered Yes / No |
```

these are the fields which we will fill up.

I know this is a database, and I was looking for anything similar in open source projects etc. but failed like I said.

A few more things that would be nice is if we could store Supplier Info, so when clicked particular supplier his info comes up, it also assigns the particular goods that supplier can ship.

Please point me in the right direction, and if you need more in order to give me a better feedback please let me know.

I have a rough idea on how all of this would work etc.

Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong things to accomplish our task.

Comment: Is your question identical to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20330/open-source-erp-with-very-flexible-shipping-module ? If not, what are the differences? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that you should find reasonably simple to implement yourself with a number of free software, database, solutions.

I would suggest giving [Libreoffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) a go as it has the option of storing the data locally or acting as the front end for a number of free database backends.

- Free/Gratis
- Base provides wizards to help users who are new to database design
- Cross Platform
- Integrated with other Libreoffice tools
- Reasonably simple for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at a [shipment tracking software](https://shypiq.com/) that helps you that provides a simple to use dashboard which records all your shipment data (including orders from different suppliers, stats of orders delivered/exempted/on time, which supplier is performing the best and also provide your customers with proactive updates regarding the delivery status of their orders