# Open source ERP with very flexible shipping module

Tags: open-source, erp, shipment

We're searching for a software that can help with quoting and shipping:

Shipping via: Air, Sea-Freight, Air-Pallets, Sea-Pallets, DHL
Calculating Shipping prices based on:
Volume or Weight (depending on which will be more expensive).
Calculating the Volume based on:
Products per Carton
Plus: Product attributes should have options for changing the size of the carton.

We searched quite long - but none of the OpenSource software we found (Magento/Drupal/Odoo/VTigerCRM/ADempiere/opentaps) was able to handle that or we aren't deep enough into it to figure out how.
Did anybody do something similar already?

Comment: In order to refine an answer; are you primarily considering integration with these carriers' current online quoting systems or are you looking for a separate quoting system?

Comment: I can't integrate with these carriers - from some we only have a XLS file with their prices.  
We'd be happy with any e-commerce system like Magento/Drupal Commerce/or similar for the frontend and the quoting system could be plugins (they don't exist yet for our specific needs) or a dedicated system like an ERP (OpenBravo/Odoo/...) which is really good with products/weights/cartons/volumes/etc. - so to integrate shop + ERP (or have it all in one system - but I doubt that exists?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [Dolibarr ERP CRM](https://www.dolibarr.org) . It's an Open Source web application with a low learning curve. May be you will have to develop a module to manager your dedicated rules for shipment prices, but this can be done easily if you have PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenBravo](http://www.openbravo.com) is open source and has a shipments module.

Here is what it looks like by default:

[image: OpenBravo shipments module]

From the [documentation](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Goods_Shipment):

> Create and manage goods shipments to your customers.
>
> Goods Shipment document registering the specifics of items sent to a customer.
>
> This window allows to browse information about all Goods Shipments registered in the system and manually create new shipment documents. It is useful if execution of some scenario is required that is not supported by automatic shipments generation process (for example, partial shipment of the order or grouping of several orders and / or invoices in one shipment). For automatic creation use Create Shipments from Orders.
>
> As described in the Costing Server article, the cost of a "Goods Shipment" is calculated as any other output transaction depending on the Costing Algorithm used.
>
> The calculated cost of a "Goods Shipment" is used while posting it to the ledger.

There is also a [Freight Management module](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Modules:Freight_Management):

[image: OpenBravo Freight Management]

> With this module you will be able to:
>
> - Define the carriers
> - Define different price lists for the same carrier. Price lists based on weight, bundles, delivery period
> - Define details of every price lists such as country/destination country, region/destination country, range of weight, bundles
> - Create price lists based on existing ones applying a coefficient
> - Define Delivery Period
> - Calculate the carriers that fit sales order conditions based on the total weight of the order
> - Calculate the freight cost of the sales order and to include it or not as a line in the document
> - Calculated in the order will be populated in the subsequent goods shipment documents